# Transfer value or item from DataBound vb code to Repeater ASP Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fes8b.jpg)        Protected Sub rptRps_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptRps.ItemDataBound

```
      If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

            Dim valueReceived As Integer = CType((CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView))("netValue"), Integer)

            If valueReceived < 0 Then

                CType(e.Item.FindControl("trItemr00"), HtmlTable).Style.Add("litLastestLog", "whatever")

                'CType(e.Item.FindControl("litLastestLog"), Label).Text = "whatever"

            End If

        End If


**********************************
<asp:Repeater ID="rptRps" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptRps_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptRps_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="tbLegenda" runat="server" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top">
.
.
.
               <td class="funHeader" style="width: 25%">
                            <asp:Literal ID="lit2LastestLog" runat="server" Text="Descr Log"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
.
.
.

 <td class="RepeaterItemCell_m" style="width: 4%; text-align: center">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastDescrLog").ToString%>
                    </td>
```

---

When I run  the conde  shows this message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I dont know what I do anymore...
I wanna show the new message here.

```
 <td class="RepeaterItemCell_m" style="width: 4%; text-align: center">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastDescrLog").ToString%>
                    </td>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oQwq.png)

Comment: `CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtDescription"),Label).text = "whatever"`

Comment: Is This  command "Dim valueReceived As String = CType((CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView))("netValue"), String)'" correct ? Do I get  the value  from Repeater to compare?

Comment: 1) make a column with description in `GridView` a `templatecolumn`. 2) use Label `ID` in the code I showed above.

Comment: I got it , but this column already exit on gridview so I want to change the old  message  wth the new  one if lower value is true.Is it possible?

Comment: Again, change the column bound to `descriptioncolumn` to `templatecolumn`. It will produce `<asp:Label ID="..."...>`. You can find this label and set new value to it. See my first comment.

Comment: Ok , I´ll do it.

Comment: I did  of this way  but it´s not running. I tried  everything.

Comment: please show your full `<asp:repeater` code including `<iItemTemplate`

Comment: I Added the pic cause it´s very dificult to update the text, sorry.

Comment: How can I do That.

Comment: `CType(e.Item.FindControl("RitStatusErDesc"),Literal).Text = "whatever"`

Comment: Perfect!!! It´s running now.

Comment: and how can I transfer image to page like this.        <td class="RepeaterItemCell_Less" style="width: 4%; text-align: center">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgStatusR" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "imgStatus").ToString %>'
                            ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusR").ToString %>' />
                    </td>   **************I need to change its image

Comment: Is it Same way?